Sigma-algebra generated by $\sin(2\omega)$
If $\Omega = (0, 2\pi)$ and $X(\omega) = \sin(2\omega)$, is $\sigma(X) = \{S: x \in S \cap [0, \pi / 4] \Leftrightarrow \pi / 2 - x \in S \cap [\pi / 4, \pi / 2] \Leftrightarrow \pi + x \in S \cap [\pi, 5\pi / 4] \Leftrightarrow 3\pi / 2 - x \in S \cap [5\pi / 4, 3\pi / 2], x \in S \cap [\pi / 2, 3\pi / 4] \Leftrightarrow \pi - x \in S \cap [3\pi / 4, \pi] \Leftrightarrow 3\pi / 2 + x \in S \cap [3\pi / 2, 7\pi / 4] \Leftrightarrow 2\pi - x \in S \cap [7\pi / 4, 2\pi]\}$?

Can you please format your fractions using proper MathJax? It makes the whole thing easier to read.

Your three first $\iff$ can be rewritten $$S\cap[0,\pi/4]=(\pi/2-S)\cap[0,\pi/4]=(S-\pi)\cap[0,\pi/4]=(3\pi/2-S)\cap[0,\pi/4],$$but your three next ones look strange:$$S\cap[\pi/2,3\pi/4]=(\pi-S)\cap[0,\pi/4]=(S-3\pi/2)\cap[0,\pi/4]=(2\pi-S)\cap[0,\pi/4].$$
I'd rather say that a subset $S\subseteq\Omega$ belongs to $\sigma(X)$ iff $$\forall x,y\in\Omega\quad[(x\in S\quad\text{and}\quad y\equiv x\text{ or }\pi/2-x\bmod\pi)\implies y\in S],$$ i.e. iff
$$(S+\pi\Bbb Z)\cap\Omega\subseteq S\quad\text{and}\quad(\pi/2-S+\pi\Bbb Z)\cap\Omega\subseteq S.$$
